# Proper use of Array and Foreach at Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I don't understand how to convert my PHP array into Laravel, I am new to Laravel and can't even find exact format to follow it. I would like to use it on my blade file. Here's my php code.

```
$properties = array('office', 'retail');
foreach ($properties as $property) :
  echo $property;
endforeach;
```

And i did my best but no luck to output the correct format from Laravel

```
$properties = array('office', 'retail')
@foreach ($properties as $property)
  {{ $property }}
@endforeach
```

Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as below :

```
 <?php $properties = array('office', 'retail'); ?>
 @foreach ($properties as $property)
    {{ $property }}
 @endforeach
```

Comment: I tried your code and yes, i learned that it should not wrapped around the <?php ?>... Thanks for the help! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is perfect and it should work if your page is a `blade` i.e., Your file name should something like `somepage.blade.php`

You shall also add another braces

```
@foreach ($properties as $property)
  {{{ $property }}}
@endforeach
```

### Update :

You should not use `{{` or `{{{` inside your php code !!!

You shall simply have like this

```
<?php
$properties = array('office', 'retail')
?>
@foreach ($properties as $property)
  {{{ $property }}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: still throws an error on my project (Whoops, looks like something went wrong). I can't guess what was the issue and does the array line correct? i did follow the one on the net, but still have an error; $array = array_add($array, 'key', 'value')

Comment: Your file name contains  is a blade right ? i.e., yourfile.blade.php ?

Comment: Instead of {{ $property can you just do this ? `@foreach ($properties as $property)
test
@endforeach` ?

Comment: I guess you are using `{{` inside php.. You should not do it ..... !! I have updated the answer, Please check it

Comment: ok, i think i got the idea... it is working now... tried Ankii Gangrade answer and it works... It should not wrapped around <?php ?>...

Answer (score 1):

Its important to first understand the working of blade control structures. Laravel 5 provides many control structures for working with blade files.

**Echoing Data**

```
Hello, {{ $name }}.

The current UNIX timestamp is {{ time() }}.
```

**Echoing Data After Checking For Existence**

Sometimes you may wish to echo a variable, but you aren't sure if the variable has been set. Basically, you want to do this:

```
{{ isset($name) ? $name : 'Default' }}
```

However, instead of writing a ternary statement, Blade allows you to use the following convenient short-cut:

```
{{ $name or 'Default' }}
```

**Displaying Raw Text With Curly Braces**

If you need to display a string that is wrapped in curly braces, you may escape the Blade behavior by prefixing your text with an @ symbol:

```
@{{ This will not be processed by Blade }}
```

If you don't want the data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```
Hello, {!! $name !!}.
```

**Docs help**

For more detail you can read the laravel docs about [Laravel Templates](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates)

**Underlying Concepts**

So basically Laravel gives you a pretty and safe way of displaying the dynamic data. The blade code is parsed by the Laravel templating engine and replaced with relevant PHP code. So if you wrapping the blade code in `<?php ?>` the Laravel will be unable to parse it and will crash.

**Analogy For Wrong Code**

Its like you have wrapped the HTML code in `<?php ?>` and expecting the HTML engine will somehow render it. Hope this will clarify your underlying blade concepts.